# Possible dimension of number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

> **What are the possibilities for the dimension $[E:\mathbb{Q}]$ of a
>   galois extensions $E/\mathbb{Q}$?**

I think I have a proof that $[E:\mathbb{Q}]$ can be any number.

First note that it will be enough to construct a galois extension of every power of every prime number $p$, since then we can use the fundamental theapply the lemma:

> If $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ with
>   $gcd([\mathbb{Q}[a]:\mathbb{Q}],[\mathbb{Q}[b]:\mathbb{Q}])=1$, then
>   $[\mathbb{Q}[a,b]:\mathbb{Q}])=[\mathbb{Q}[a]:\mathbb{Q}]\cdot [\mathbb{Q}[b]:\mathbb{Q}]$

(Edit) Also, if $\mathbb{Q}[a],\mathbb{Q}[b]$ are galois then so is $\mathbb{Q}[a,b]$, since if $f_a,f_b$ are the minimal polynomials of $a,b$ (which are seperable and normal) then $\mathbb{Q}[a,b]$ is the splitiing field of $f_a \cdot f_b$, which is again normal and seperable.

So, to constuct an extension of dimension $p^n$, Use [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) and take a prime $q$ s.t. $q=1mod(p^n)$. Then $p^n|q-1$. Look at $K=\mathbb{Q}[\rho_q]$ (where $\rho_q$ is the $q$-th root of unity). We know that the galois group is $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})=U_q$ (The Euler group of order $q$).

Now  $U_q$ is cyclic, so it has a subgroup of any order dividing it. In particular, take a subgroup of order $\frac{q-1}{p^n}$. By the galoios correspondence, there is suitable field $E$, with $[K:E]=\frac{q-1}{p^n}$, so $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=p^n$. $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is a galois extension since the group is commutative, so any subgroup is normal.

$$\\$$

Is this proof true? Also, what can be said about non-commutative groups? Is there a number field of any dimension with non-commutative galois group (where such a group exists)?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem.

Comment: You could give a little argument that $\mathbb Q(a,b)/\mathbb Q$ is still a galois extension in your lemma. For example, note that it is the splitting field of the product of the minimal polynomials of $a$ and $b$ (provided that the two smaller extensions were galois extensions).

Comment: @MooS You are right, Thank you. I'll edit it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The arrgument there is indeed similar to my argument.

Comment: As for your second question, of course the problem is that in some dimensions there are no noncommutative groups of the corresponding size (e.g. any prime dimension).

Comment: Yes, I meant whenever it is possible

Comment: As the Wikipedia article will tell you, Shafarevich showed that every finite solvable group occurs as a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$, so that takes care of a lot of possible dimensions. But I don't know much about sizes for which there is a nonabelian finite group but no nonabelian finite solvable group.